# I am having trouble writing a for...in loop based on a condition in JavaScript [beginner]

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, for-loop

I am trying to modify the function to return the count of how many people are 16 or older. I know that I need a for...in loop. That's about as far as I got. Please help.

```
function countLegalDrivers(people){

}

const examplePeopleArray = [
  { name: 'John', age: 15},
  { name: 'Jane', age: 16},
  { name: 'Jack', age: 17}
];

console.log(countLegalDrivers(examplePeopleArray), '<-- should be 2');
```

Comment: Use .filter() on the array

Comment: This seems like a homework question, so I can't answer as it would be a disservice to you. You would use a for(p in people). Inside of that loop you would use a simple if statement that checks if the age is either a comparison operator to verify if they can drive. Don't forget to return the value.

Comment: `for...in` is the last thing you would do on an array. Consider `for...of`, or `.filter`.

Answer (score 0):

### you can do with filter or without filter as well

```js
// with filter 
 function countLegalDrivers(people) {
   return people.filter(p => p.age >= 16).length;
 }

// with ordinary for loop
/* function countLegalDrivers(people) {
  var count = 0;
  for(var i=0;i<people.length;i++){
    if(people[i].age>=16){
      count++;
    }
  }
  return count;
}
*/

const examplePeopleArray = [
  { name: "John", age: 15 },
  { name: "Jane", age: 16 },
  { name: "Jack", age: 17 }
];

console.log(countLegalDrivers(examplePeopleArray));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  function countLegalDrivers(people){
  return people.reduce((prev,cur)=>prev+(cur.age>=16?1:0),0);
}

const examplePeopleArray = [
  { name: 'John', age: 15},
  { name: 'Jane', age: 16},
  { name: 'Jack', age: 17}
];

console.log(countLegalDrivers(examplePeopleArray), '<-- should be 2');
```

The `Array.prototype.reduce` function is easily to resoleve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

As [synchrodynamic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8940493/synchrodynamic) points out, this sounds like a homework problem, so I won't post a complete answer here. However, I think it *would* be fair to tell you that this is the wrong tool for the job. `for...in` is used to iterate through pairs of keys and values within an object, and per the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in), it should **not** be used to iterate through the elements within in an array (which is what you have here). Instead, a simple `for` loop (or, alternatively, one of the iteration methods mentioned in other comments) should suffice.